# PHP - How can i insert a "fixed" string into database?

Tags: php

i want to do something like that:

When you insert the POST:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />

<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$string = "M";

//code to insert $name AND $string together into database table

?>
```

I want to put a fixed string in front from this variable, and i want my query to read like this:

```
$name + M
```

Lets imagine that the name is George, i want to insert the name George into database, with an M

Like this: George M

How can i do that?

Comment: `$name = $_POST['name']. ' M'`;

Comment: `$name = $_POST['name'] . ' M';` http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: either your question is too easy or you are not explaining it correctly, or its too broad... Think on it, make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$string = "M";
$full_string = $name . " " . $string;

//code to insert $full_string into database table
```